# MFC Dialog Class Wizard - trying to generate classes in separate includes & src directories

Tags: visual-studio, mfc

We are halfway through an MFC project, trying to rearrange the source and header files into src and includes directories on the disk. The only way we found to do this is to move the files in the computer directory, then create mirror directories in Visual Studios, and "add existing" files to those directories, then remove all the files from the base directory in VS.

However, when editing or creating dialogs the wizard cannot locate the correct class to edit/create, and will generate a new file (named existing_class.CPP, instead of existing_class.cpp). To overcome this issue, we also tried to generate a  new class, manually adding the path (includes\file_name.h and src\file_name.cpp) when using the class wizard. This almost works correctly, adding the files correctly to the right directories, and when adding a variable the wizard functions correctly.

However when adding an event handler, the message is created in the right location, but the function sub is added to a newly generated file (file_name.CPP). Any advice on how to work in MFC/VS using separated includes/src directories?

Comment: Pragmatic advice: Don't fiddle with project settings you don't fully understand. Instead of moving files to physical directories, use the IDE's built-in features to arrange files into folders (filters). If you insist on moving files to filesystem folders, your only other option is to learn how to write MFC code without using wizards.

Comment: Thank you for your advice IInspectable! I would like to do this. I am intimidated by manually editing the resource file to manage dialog controls. I feel confident creating windows/window controls, but I don't know how to manage the dialogs well without wizards.

Comment: The wizard eventually stops working for one reason or another. You don't have to use a text editor for the dialog. Use the resource editor. If you double click on the controls, the wizard may try to put the handlers in a different cpp/header file. Just copy/paste the code in to your own file.

Comment: In my experience if there are problems with the wizard shut down VS. Rename your main project folder. Then rename it back. You do this to change the time stamp of the project folder. Then start VS. This triggers it to rebuild the classwizard database. But, as for moving files etc I tend you do things with VisualAssist as there places not immediately obvious where files are referred to (like in the solution files etc.) that need updating.